How to make a 3D ripple effect like the one shown?
How would I create the following 3d image and make it very similar. It doesn’t need to be exact. I’ve played around with drops falling on a water surface and probably could stop the animation at a suitable point and export an stl file. Is there a better way.  I’ve seen YouTube video examples in other software but not in blender that I’m aware of. Appreciate any help

Here are 2 examples with Geometry Nodes. It's basically some math over a noise texture. The left example is composed of straight waves, the right one is composed of sin waves.

Straight waves
This one is made by passing a noise texture through a Ping-Pong node. The Scale of this node is the width of the waves

Sin waves
For this one we plug the noise texture into a Sine node. We can control the frequency by multiplying the noise texture.

You can easily use this technique in different cases, assuming you'll adapt the geometry nodes accordingly.
Why does it produce that shape ?
The waves your image shows are what you could call equipotential lines of a noise texture : regions that share a similar value. Any 2 regions with identical values should appear identical. You can think of it as perpendicular to radials (lines that go from black to white).
You can visualize that on the next image. Each colored line is an equipotential line : the texture under the line will be constant. You'll notice that indeed the color is the same alongside the line.

I've increased the contrast of the texture to see it better.
Because one line shares the same texture value, it will also share the same ping-pong or sin value, creating these concentric waves.

Thanks for taking the time to produce this answer I appreciate it…
